# Does retention policy affect the database size on disk?

Tags: time-series, influxdb, retention

Even after InfluxDB (v0.11) deleted the expired data from database, the size of the database remains the same on disk.
Has anyone faced the same problem or am I doing something wrong.
Ideally after expiry of the data the size of the database should decrease right?
Also just to verify how do any of you check database size on local machine.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @DieterMeemken ok so I'm trying to determine InfluxDB storage for exactly 1M data points. Something like [link](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/data-storage-tests/data-storage-test/). After all the data points have been written, I'm checking the database size in /var/lib/Influxdb/data/<db_name>. After the duration mentioned in the retention policy I'm checking the database size once more but the size hasn't changed even though the data is deleted.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like this. Can you give me some steps to try to reproduce it.